# What is the proper name of a zip-like method that "pivots" a list of lists?

Tags: functional-programming

Given a list of lists, such as `((a b c d) (e f g h) (i j k l) (m n o p) (q r s t))`, I'd like to write a transformation to a new list of lists consisting of the first item from each list, followed the second item from each list, etc. (in my example, the result of this would be `((a e i m q) (b f j n r) (c g k o s) (d h l p t))`).

Does this operation have a distinct name, apart from `zip`? If so, what is that name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best word for it is probably [transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose).

Your list of lists can be thought of as a matrix, and this is a matrix transposition.

Answer (score 6):

In Haskell, this function is called [transpose](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3atranspose).

Answer (score 4):

For questions like this, I usually turn to Hoogle for inspiration. Once we've sorted out the type signature for your function, [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5B%5Ba%5D%5D%20-%3E%20%5B%5Ba%5D%5D) tells us that haskell uses both [transpose](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3atranspose) and [sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3asequence) perform this transformation (though you have to squint a bit at sequence to notice that it means the same thing for the list monad).

Transpose seems better as a list specific operation, but sequence makes a lot of sense when working with other monads.

Comment: Thanks! I wish every language had something like Hoogle.